# Is there a way to fill the empty cell above index title in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know that I can use `df.index.name()` to put a title on my index and it will return the index name in a new row, something like:

```
        column1    column2
index
  0       foo        bar
```

And I already did it, but I still need to save the timestamp on that df, and for organization purposes (it will be saved periodically in an excel file), I would like to put it in the "apparently empty" cell above the index, something like:

```
timestamp    column1    column2
  index
    0          foo        bar
```

Is there a way to make it work? I'm looking through pandas docs but so far I found nothing...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way in pandas.
But what's wrong with `df.index.name = 'timestamp'`?, giving you

```
          column1 column2
timestamp
0             foo     bar
```

If it's just about how the printed data frame looks like, you could do the following:

```
df.index.name = 'index'
print('timestamp', repr(df)[6:])
```

Comment: Not wrong at all, I just need to find a way to save the timestamp in the DataFrame, but I don't want to make a new row just for it (but apparently this is the best way to do it)...
It will be saved to an excel file, so I was thinking I could just use the first cell that will be left empty to save that timestamp.
PS: optimization counts since it will be constantly generating those dataframes in a low spec raspberry...

Comment: @LucasTeixeira - perhaps research modifying an Excel file (using openpyxl or xlsxwriter, for example)?

Comment: @BigBen I though about it, but perhaps the cost of implementation it will not be worthy for such a little thing, I think since pandas can't do it alone, maybe just save that timestamp in a new row will be better. But thanks anyway for you tip! :)

Comment: @LucasTeixeira when using [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), just make sure to set `index=True` and `index_labelstr='timestamp'` (if you did not set the index name before). This includes the index column (named 'timestamp') in your Excel sheet.

Comment: @MrJ If I got what you mean (set the index.title as the timestamp) The problem is: sometimes the index is data too, like Rank or ID, and not only an index as in "[0, 1, 2, ...]" :/

Comment: @LucasTeixeira – No problem, you can set `df.index = [0.1, 0.2, 'a', ...]` or whatever else you want. Does not have to be an integer index and does not have to be unique.